# Red5 flex streamer: "Scope StreamRecorder/test not found on 127.0.0.1"

Tags: apache-flex, video-streaming, red5

I downloaded the red5-flex-streamer ( http://code.google.com/p/red5-flex-streamer/ ) and followed the instructions but when I'm trying to connect to the Red5 server it always says that "Scope StreamRecorder/test not found on 127.0.0.1".
("test" is the username I gave "http://red5-flex-streamer.loc/record.php?user=test")
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade the Red5 server 1.0 to 0.9. Voila, it's working now!